# How to disable fake SSL check in development phase for Opera 17+ and Chrom 30+

Tags: ssl, opera

During the test, we are configuring our web server(Tomcat) to be connected to with test SSL
When we try to connect to this site with IE, we face this error:

```
There is a problem with this website's security certificate

The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority..
.............
```

..............

But At the end the we have an option which mentions:

```
Continue to this website (not recommended).
```

So we can continue to view our site.

Something same happens when we use Firefox.

But when I visit my site in Opera I got this error, and **I can not go on**:

```
Invalid Server Certificate

You attempted to reach localhost, but the server presented an invalid certificate.
```

Any comments!! How can I disable this. I see some related posts but non of them helped!

Comment: Have you imported the certificate into the  certificate store within the os?  Firefox uses its own  certificate store.

Comment: No but are there any setting which I can force Opera not to by pass this checking! I see this issue in Chrome too

Comment: Are you using the version of Opera which is now a semi-fork of Chrome?   The real solution to this problem is to import the cert. This problem would exist with IE also.

Comment: I have downloaded opera from http://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/17.0.1241.45/win/Opera_17.0.1241.45_Setup.exe. Yes it is same as chrome! As I mentioned the IE and Also Fireworks have some tweaks and let you by pass this. If there is no solution, well I should try to import SSL certification.

Comment: You can either make the certificate valid or import it.  But Opera and Chrome should both provide a mechanic to ignore the invalid certificate and display the website.